# Determine the area of a shaded region between two curves

Tags: calculus

$y = x$

$y = x^2 - 2$

I can't determine the correct answer with all the calculations I am doing. Am I supposed to integrate with respect to $y$ or $x$ and what exactly are these integrals because I am finding the intersections to be $(2,2)$ at the right and $(-1,-1)$ at the left.

Comment: The way this question is posed does not really make sense. Could you write explicitly what the question asks?

Comment: It says "Determine the area of the shaded region in the following figures." So (y=x) is one equation and (y=x^2-2) is another equation. You graph them and the region where those two functions intersect is what you are trying to find.

Comment: This makes more sense. When I first read the question it had y=yx or something.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

As you noticed, the two curves intersect at $x=-1$ and $x=2$. So the integrals have to be taken between these two bounds. You must have noticed that $y=x$ is always greater than $y=x^2-2$ over the considered range. So the area is given by $$S=\int_{-1}^2 (x- (x^2-2)) \, dx$$

I am sure that you remember that, in general, the antiderivative of $x^n$ is $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

I am sure that you can take from here and finish.

Comment: Wow lol I've been doing that the whole time but I've been subtracting 60/18 and 21/18 because it was negative but I'm supposed to add them. Thanks a lot tho

Comment: Then, you have a mistake somewhere. The antiderivative you are supposed to have found is $$-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^2}{2}+2 x$$ which leads to the answer in the book. Check your calculations and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Given equation of the curves are:

$ y = x$ ... (i)

$ y = x^2-2$ ... (ii)

To determine the area of a shaded region between these curves, we need to sketch the curves on a graph.
[image]

Now, we can see the shaded region between two curves,  $y = x$ and $y = x^2-2$

**Area of Shaded Region between Two Curves :**

$A = \displaystyle \int _a^b [ f (x) - g(x)] dx$

where, $f(x)$ is top curve

$g(x)$ is bottom curve

$a$ (Lower limit) = $x$ coordinate of extreme left intersection point of area to be found.

$b$ (Upper limit) = $x$ coordinate of extreme right intersection point of area to be found

So, $f(x) = y = x$

$ g(x) = y = x^2 - 2$

We need to find the limits, $a$ and $b$.

**How to Find the Limits ?**

Since the limits, $a$ and $b$, are the $x$ coordinates of the intersection points of the curve.

So, we will find the intersection points of the given curves.

Putting the value of $y$ from equation (i) into equation (ii)

$\Rightarrow x = x^2-2 $

$\Rightarrow x^2-x-2=0$

$\Rightarrow x^2-2x+x-2=0$

$\Rightarrow x(x-2)+1(x-2)=0$

$\Rightarrow (x+1)(x-2)=0$

$x = -1$ and $x=2$

Putting the values of $x$ in equation (i)

$y = -1$ and $y = 2$

Thus, points of intersection are $A (-1, -1)$ and $B(2, 2)$

$\therefore a = -1$ and $ b = 2$

**Area between Curves :**

The area will be

$A = \displaystyle\int_{-1} ^{2} [(x)-(x^2-2)] dx$

$ =\displaystyle\int_{-1} ^{2}(x-x^2+2) dx $

$A = \displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2} x \; dx-
\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2} x^2 \; dx +
\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{2} 2 \; dx $

$=\left [ \dfrac {x^2}{2} \right ]_{-1}^2-
\left [ \dfrac {x^3}{3} \right ]_{-1}^2 +
\left [ 2x \right ]_{-1}^2 $

$=\left [ \dfrac {4}{2}-\dfrac {1}{2} \right ] -
\left [ \dfrac {8}{3}- \left (\dfrac {-1}{3} \right) \right ] +
[4 -(-2)] $

$ =\dfrac {3}{2}-3+6$

$A=\dfrac {9}{2}$ or $4.5$

This is the required answer.
[image]